Do standard/reference eNodeB LTE signals with different bandwidths have the same power or same PSD?
Or are both the power and PSD different for different BWs?
I tried to go through the LTE specification document but couldn't find this information. Or maybe I missed it somewhere (it is 600 pages after all).

the amount of power that a radio unit emits is pretty much up to the radio unit. Why would you expect it to be identical?

Does 3GPP specify eNB power as a function of bandwidth?
To the best of my knowledge, 3GPP specifications do not define eNodeB transmit power as a function of bandwidth. From signal processing perspective, I don't see why.
Does 3GPP specify eNB power in their standards?
Yes, 3GPP standards specify eNodeB power, particularly in TS 36.141 Clause 6.2 "Base station output power". Check Table 6.2.1-1: Base Station rated output power.
However, actual power levels and compliance are regulated by regional authorities like the FCC. For regulatory notes, refer to documents such as TS 36.104 Annex H.
36.523 is not what you would like to skim for such information.

If you go through 3GPP 36.104 , section 6.2, you can see that transmit power of eNodeB in Table 6.2.1 is independent of the bandwidth. But there are some additional requirements for Band 34 and Band 41 for certain bandwidths depending on the region. These are mentioned in sec 6.2.2. So I suggest to read these sections to get a clearer picture. The total power emitted by base station can be distributed among the sub-carriers depending on the allocation. This can change the PSD. But the total power has to be within the limit specified above.
